# When changing the hostname of a server, can a CNAME be used with the old name for backwards compatibility?

Tags: dns, vps, name

We have a VPS hosting a few of dozen sites at `server.example.com`. We're deploying 3 more VPSs this week to cope with growth & want to change our naming structure.

E.g. `s1.example.com`, `s2.example.com`, `s3.example.com`, etc.

If we change the hostname of our current server, is there a way we can set an alias (like a CNAME) so that we don't have to change the config of every device that connects to us for mail services? Currently almost 80 devices.

Comment: Generally you would want to use both the old and new hostname for the mail server. You simply setup the virtual host file to use both hostname names. That way people using old mail settings can still send and receive email. You generally wouldn't want to do this in the DNS settings because its limited, Just keep the old hostname pointing to the mail server and setup the new to do the same.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Would you know which virtual hosts file I'd need to edit? Using Centos 7 with WHM/cPanel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly acceptable for multiple host names to refer to the same IP address (and server).   So yes, use a CNAME with the old name of your VPS so that all the devices that connect with that name can continue to do so without re-configuration.